# Pyside QWidgetList item assign multiple icons

Tags: python, icons, pyside, qlistwidget, pyside2

I know how to assign 1 icon to an item in a QWidgetList. Is it possible to assign more than 1 icon? Like in the image I've attached, I'd like to add a second icon (the green one) to 'a' and be able to remove it on certain conditions. The code below is a just an example of what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.orange = QIcon('orangeIconPath')
        self.green = QIcon('greenIconPath')
        self.layout=QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.widget1=QWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget1)

        self.layout1=QVBoxLayout()
        self.widget1.setLayout(self.layout1)

        self.layout1.addWidget(QLabel("First layout"))
        self.qlist = QListWidget()
        self.layout1.addWidget(self.qlist)

        items = ['a','b','c']
        self.qlist.addItems(items)

        #This is where I'm struggling when it's more than 1 icon
        #enter a condition to check against each item and assign icon/s to the item when condition is met

        self.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not with a `QListWidget`, at least not on its own.

You have a number of options available to you, though.

My personal preference in this case is to use `QTreeWidget`. A `QTreeWidget` acts very much like a `QListWidget` with multiple columns, so you can put icons in those columns. You'll need to fiddle with it some to configure the column widths and maybe remove the header bar if you don't want it there, but it isn't particularly difficult (and I'd be happy to provide additional advice if needed). You can also use `QTableWidget` for the same purpose but it takes more configuration to get it to behave like a list.

Another option would be to programmatically generate new icons with multiple icons side-by-side so you're only setting a single image.

Significantly more advanced would be to [create a delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#a-simple-delegate) for the view. I won't go into detail on this here because it's a LOT of work, but it also gives you the most control.

---

As a side note, I would recommend against using `QListWidget` 
/ `QTreeWidget` / `QTableWidget` view classes. They're really easy to pick up, true, but it really is worth familiarizing yourself with using the model-view `QListView` / `QTreeView` / `QTableView` classes. It's super easy to write a `QAbstractListModel` or `QAbstractTableModel` subclass of your own, or you can use `QStringListModel` for simple lists and `QStandardItemModel` as a stepping stone between the two types of view classes.

Comment: Hey Coda, thanks for that explanation, I actually didn't know it would be better to use QListView/QTreeView/QTableView instead of QListWidget / QTreeWidget / QTableWidget. Like you said they are easier to learn and have way more examples online to refer to. I shall definitely read up on them right away. If you have any links or videos that I can refer to, that would be great. I did look up the link for delegate, that right now looks like it's out of my scope. I'll delve into that once I grasp QListView / QTreeView / QTableView Classes and their parent classes. Thanks!

Comment: The documentation on doc.qt.io is written for C++, but it's reasonably good and the API is mostly consistent with PySide, so I'd start here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#creating-new-models

Comment: The big advantage of using the model-view code is that you have a LOT more control over how the data is structured and managed. You get to interface directly with the data, instead of having to write code that's responsible for translating between items and the data structures you're working with. List and table models are REALLY easy -- just subclass and override `data()` (and maybe `setData()`) and read/write your backend data structures inside those functions.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll have to go through that, and understand it, my C++ skills aren't the best, but hopefully should be enough to understand it. I haven't done any overrides in Qt (or in general, but I do understand what it does) so this will be new to me to try. If you don't mind, I'll hit you up if I get stuck on anything, it will be a while though as it's a lot to go over.